# Set directive to input field using a method

Tags: angular

I am trying to set a directive to an input field using a method in my TS file. Basically I want to set the directive which is called `appOskInput` when I set focus to the input field using my method in the TS file called `isKeyboardActive`.

Here is my code

*HTML*

```
<form-input
    appOskInput
    (inputChanged)="onInputChanged($event,'accountNumber')"
    (blurChanged)="onBlurChanged($event)"
    [formStatus]="formStatus"
    [parentFormGroup]="setupForm"
    [data]="{
      formControlName: 'accountNumber',
      name: 'accountNumber',
      label: Accounnt Number
    }">
</form-input>

<a (click)="isKeyboardActive()" class="use-kepypad"><img class="mouse-icon" src="assets/images/ford/mouse-computer.png"> <img class="mouse-icon" src="assets/images/ford/mouse-computer-hover.png">{{ 'preLogon.common.label.useKeypad'|translate }}</a>
```

*TS*

```
@ViewChild(FormInputComponent, { read: ElementRef }) formInput: ElementRef;

isKeyboardActive() {
  const input = this.formInput.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
  input.focus();
}
```

Directive

```
import {
  Directive,
  OnInit,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  Optional,
  EventEmitter,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { KeyboardService } from './keyboard.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appOskInput]',
})
export class OskInputDirective implements OnInit {
  private keySubscription: Subscription;
  private backspaceSubscription: Subscription;
  private enterSubscription: Subscription;
  private measure: HTMLElement;
  private inputEl: HTMLInputElement;
  private isBlurTrue: boolean = false;
  @Output() inputChanged = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() blurChanged = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    @Optional() private control: NgControl,
    private el: ElementRef,
    private keyboard: KeyboardService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let thisStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this.el.nativeElement);
    this.measure = document.createElement('span');
    this.measure.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.measure.style.right = '100%';
    this.measure.style.font = thisStyle.font;
    document.body.appendChild(this.measure);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      this.inputEl = this.el.nativeElement;
      return;
    }
    this.inputEl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
  }

  @HostListener('focus')
  private onFocus() {
    this.isBlurTrue = false;
    this.blurChanged.emit(this.isBlurTrue);
    this.keyboard.fireKeyboardRequested(true);
    this.subscribeToKeyboardEvents();
  }

  @HostListener("onBlur")
  private onBlur() {
    this.isBlurTrue = true;
    this.blurChanged.emit(this.isBlurTrue);
    this.keyboard.fireKeyboardRequested(false);
    this.unsubscribeFromKeyboardEvents();
  }

  private subscribeToKeyboardEvents() {
    this.keySubscription = this.keyboard.keyPressed.subscribe((key) =>
      this.onKey(key)
    );
    this.backspaceSubscription = this.keyboard.backspacePressed.subscribe((_) =>
      this.onBackspace()
    );
    this.enterSubscription = this.keyboard.enterPressed.subscribe((_) =>
      this.onEnter()
    );
  }

  private unsubscribeFromKeyboardEvents() {
    this.keySubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.backspaceSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.enterSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  private onKey(key: string) {
    let element = this.inputEl,
      start = element.selectionStart,
      end = element.selectionEnd;
    this.measure.textContent = element.value.substr(0, start) + key;
    element.value = element.value.substr(0, start) + key + element.value.substr(end);
    if (this.control) this.control.control.setValue(element.value);
    element.focus();
    element.selectionStart = element.selectionEnd = start + 1;
    this.inputChanged.emit(element.value);
    this.updateScrollPosition();
  }

  private onBackspace() {
    let element = this.inputEl,
      start = element.selectionStart,
      end = element.selectionEnd;

    if (start == 0) {
      return;
    }

    if (start == end) {
      start--;
    }

    this.measure.textContent = element.value.substr(0, start);
    element.value = element.value.substr(0, start) + element.value.substr(end);
    if (this.control) this.control.control.setValue(element.value);
    element.focus();
    element.selectionStart = element.selectionEnd = start;
    this.inputChanged.emit(element.value);
    this.updateScrollPosition();
  }

  private updateScrollPosition() {
    let element = this.el.nativeElement;
    element.scrollLeft = this.measure.offsetWidth - (element.clientWidth - 10);
  }

  private onEnter() {
    const ev = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      code: 'Enter',
      key: 'Enter'
    });
    this.el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(ev);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify a question a bit? It seems like `appOskInput` is already attached to `form-input`, right? And you're saying that it needs to be set to input field

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes, but I would like call it in my method `isKeyboardActive()` as I need to call it without having to always click within the input field.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I think you're talking about adding directive dynamically on DOM? is this what you;re asking for?

Comment: @PankajParkar yes

I am currently trying to do something like this `@ViewChildren(OskInputDirective) appOskInput;` and then call `this.appOskInput;` in the `isKeyboardActive()` method

Comment: yes, that is completely possible. where are you stuck with that? Just a note. You can use `this.appOskInput` to call the public methods that exist on it. (TBH I don't think this is a good idea to solve this problem). But you may try if that first works for you or not

Comment: @PankajParkar tried the above that I mentioned in the comment but does not seem to set the directive correctly

Comment: Can you please tell me? what you have tried?

Comment: I tried `@ViewChildren(OskInputDirective) appOskInput;` and then call `this.appOskInput;` in the `isKeyboardActive()` method

Here is a stackblitz of something I based my functionality of

https://stackblitz.com/edit/onscreen-keyboard-ajten3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fkeyboard.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fkeyboard-key.directive.ts

Comment: any error there? I saw interesting thing about `appOskInput` elment, it expect host element to be `input` element, perhaps that's the reason it is not working and `form-input` is not `input` element

Comment: I found that I need to click twice on order for the keyboard to show so it may be an initializing issue. I will need to debug to see why

Comment: can you try like `setTimeout(() => appOskInput.onFocus())` just to check if anything related to change detection?

Comment: @PankajParkar tried it but still an issue. Let me debug to see what fires off first